# AWS Cognito check and resume session (iOS)

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, session, amazon-cognito

I'm using Amazon Cognito with MobileHub on iOS. I've spent the whole day figuring out how to check and resume a session to make the login seamless.

I was able to sign in and sign up users but to make them open the app and the app checking the session (to see if they're not logged out/user was disabled from the user pool) and then if everything passes they're automatically logged in - this I can't figure out. The docs are not at all helpful and I've tried using resumeSession and other random methods but nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

The resume session should be called from your app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. Mobile Hub does this in the `AWSMobileClient.swift` file with callbacks from your app delegate. You can follow the getting started instructions on Mobile Hub console to integrate the `AWSMobileClient.swift` file. This file could be located in the `AmazonAws` folde of the sample app or minimal SDK which you download.

Thanks,
Rohan

Comment: Yea I just realized it's in the AWSMobileClient.swift folder. But the problem is, it never fails to resume the session, even if I delete a user from the user pool.